# AEM : How can I extend the vanity URL?

Tags: aem

*Environment* : AEM 6.0

*Site* : https://docker.demo.com

*Page* : /content/home/welcome

*Vanity URL* : wel

*Step* : I enter "https://docker.demo.com/wel"

*Crrent Result* : The browser it will redirect me to "https://docker.demo.com/**content**/home/welcome.html"

*Expected Result* : The browser it will redirect me to "https://docker.demo.com/home/welcome.html"

Does anyone know how to extend Vanity to achieve this function?

Thanks
Forrest

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is a vanity url issue. I rather guess that you do not have path shortening and mapping configured.

By the way - if this is just a "test": Do not waste your time with AEM 6.0. This version is pretty outdated.

hth,
OliG